# How to make <klass>.any_instance the subject

Tags: ruby, rspec2

Right now I have lots of the following:

```
it{ ::Api.any_instance.should_receive(...).once; start }
```

Rspec chokes if I try to make `::Api.any_instance` the subject, i.e.

```
subject{ ::Api.any_instance }
it{ should_receive(...).once; start }
```

Is there a way to DRY these specs?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the design of the specs.

What I would suggest is to do:

```
describe SomeClass do
  let(:object_instance) { described_class.new } 

  before do
    # Put expectations in before block, they shouldn't be a part of text example!
    object_instance.should_receive(:something)
  end

  specify { subject.do_something_else }
end
```

If you have more expectations to meet you can put all of them into `before` block or just use different `context`s.

If lots of specs looks similar I would opt for extracting this into shared example.